# Dozer mapping from list of Strings to another list

Tags: java, object, mapping, dozer

I need to map two objects.

Object 1 having list of primitive String
Object 2 having list of custom objects.

Is this possible in Dozer?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10602740/1343161) is an answer about string to enum mapping, it might help.

Comment: It depends upon the custom object. Can you specify your source and destination object?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a CustomConverter to handle these objects. I don't think this is working out of the box. Check the [Customer Converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html) documentation.