# Dozer : String-To-Date Field Level Mapping for a List

Tags: java, date, java-7, dozer

I want to map a `DTO` (all are of String Data Types) to `VO` (contains String,int,boolean,Date)

**StudentDTO**

```
private StudentDetailDTO student;
```

**StudentDetailDTO :**

```
private String sid;
private String name;
private String createDt;
private String studentInd;
private List<FeeReceiptDTO> feeDetails;
```

**FeeReceiptDTO:**

```
private String semisterNum;
private String feeAmount;
private String paidOn;
```

**StudentDetailVO :**

```
private int sid;
private String name;
private Date createDt;
private boolean studentInd;
private List<FeeReceiptVO> feeDetails;
```

**FeeReceiptVO:**

```
private int semisterNum;
private Double feeAmount;
private Date paidOn;
```

I am using `DOZZER` to map my DTO to VO [String-to-Date-DozzerMapping](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/stringtodatemapping.html)

**DozzerMapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">

    <mapping date-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" map-null="true" map-empty-string="true" wildcard="true" type="one-way" >
        <class-a>com.college.student.dto.StudentDTO</class-a>
        <class-b>com.college.student.vo.StudentVO</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>student.sid</a>
            <b>sid</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>student.name</a>
            <b>name</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>student.createDt</a>
            <b>createDt</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>student.studentInd</a>
            <b>studentInd</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a date-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm">student.feeDetails</a>
            <b>feeDetails</b>
        </field>

    </mapping>
</mappings>
```

But, the Date in the feeDetails i.e., `paidOn` is unable to format from String to Date.

Am i doing something wrong?

Do i need to write a `CustomStringToDateConvertor` just for this `paidOn` field?

**Error Log :**

```
ERROR [org.dozer.MappingProcessor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-1) Field mapping error -->
  MapId: null
  Type: null
  Source parent class: com.college.student.dto.StudentDTO
  Source field name: paidOn
  Source field type: class java.lang.String
  Source field value: 01/01/2015 01:01
  Dest parent class: com.college.student.vo.StudentVO
  Dest field name: paidOn
  Dest field type: java.util.Date: org.dozer.converters.ConversionException: Unable to determine time in millis of source object
    at org.dozer.converters.DateConverter.convert(DateConverter.java:81) [dozer-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.dozer.converters.PrimitiveOrWrapperConverter.convert(PrimitiveOrWrapperConverter.java:70) [dozer-5.4.0.jar:]
```

I tried to Debug and i found that `dateFormat` for this date is coming as `null` in the Date convertor of Dozzer `org.dozer.converters.DateConvertor`

I defined the `date-format` at `field-level` but it is not effected for `List` of Objects.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Is this field level declaration correct `<field>
            <a date-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm">student.feeDetails</a>
            <b>feeDetails</b>
        </field>` - will dozer take this date-format, both of them are util.List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As,Dozer is not able to convert `String-To-Date - At Field Level Mapping for a List`.

I had defined a new mapping for the List i.e., considering it as a `Object`

I Changed the **DozerMapper.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">

<mapping date-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" map-null="true" map-empty-string="true" wildcard="true" type="one-way" >
        <class-a>com.college.student.dto.FeeReceiptDTO</class-a>
        <class-b>com.college.student.vo.FeeReceiptVO</class-b>
</mapping>

    <mapping date-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" map-null="true" map-empty-string="true" wildcard="true" type="one-way" >
        <class-a>com.college.student.dto.StudentDTO</class-a>
        <class-b>com.college.student.vo.StudentVO</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>student.sid</a>
            <b>sid</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>student.name</a>
            <b>name</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>student.createDt</a>
            <b>createDt</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>student.studentInd</a>
            <b>studentInd</b>
        </field>
        <field>
            <a>student.feeDetails</a>
            <b>feeDetails</b>
        </field>

    </mapping>
</mappings>
```